# Scheduling tool that shows people's overlapping calendar availability?

Tags: web-apps, calendar, google-calendar

I'm looking for a free web-based tool that will find the common availability of 3 people.

I've spent a couple hours researching meeting scheduling apps/sites. The only tool that seemed to meet my needs was www.meetomatic.com, but it looks like it no longer exists.

It seems like with most tools, you have to FIRST propose a few tentative meeting times, and polling features allow people to weigh in and vote on which of those proposed times work for them. And then with some of them, the app automatically schedules the meeting.

I don't want that. I want everyone to enter ALL their available time, then be given a view of ALL the times during the week when everyone is available at the same time.

Does such a tool exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Doodle? http://doodle.com/ Best I've found out there.

Free to use.

[image]

Comment: How does Doodle meet the requirements? Are there any draw-backs which need to be considered? "Best" is always subjective. But answers should consist of more than just a link.

Answer (score 3):

I did a bunch of digging today. The best one I've found is http://whenisgood.net - no sign in required and supports time zones.

https://www.omnipointment.com looks promising, but requires you to sign in with Facebook, Google, Github, or Twitter, doesn't currently support time zones and limits you to scheduling 3 meetings for free.

www.fasterplan.com is a widely recommended one and it supports availability ranges, but doesn't support multiple time zones and only shows periods of overlap for EVERYONE, it doesn't let you see, for example, good times for everyone but Bob.

Comment: A bit more information about each would be nice, also, if you could split up these answers, that would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://wishfulsyncing.com is exactly that.

- no predefined times
- no account required
- free

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing more details - like a review.